# Comments to every post (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

*Sorry if being such a noob!*

I'm currently working on a blog page with posts. I have already set up a CMS where you can create new posts (with the following method..)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['PostName'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['PostContent'])) {
            addPost($_POST['PostName'],$_POST['PostAuth'],$_POST['PostContent'],$_POST['PostCats'],$_POST['PostDay'],$_POST['PostMonth'],$_POST['PostYear'],$_POST['PostImage'],$post_count);
            header("Location: addPost.php");


        } else { "text empty";

        }

    } else {
        echo "title empty";
        include('back1.php'); 
    }

} else {
    header("Location: back2.php");
}
```

---

```
function addPost($pName, $pAuth, $pContent, $pCat = 1, $pDay, $pMonth, $pYear, $pImage) {   
   $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts
              VALUES(null,'$pName','$pAuth',
                    '$pContent','$pCat',
                    '$pDay','$pMonth',
                    '$pYear','$pImage')") or die(mysql_error()); 
}
```

However, I want a unique comment field to every post.

I already know how to set up a form that that post details to the MySQL, and then a get function to view it on the page. But which method should I use if I want a unique comment field for every post? Since they can't have the same table etc...

Comment: Add a `unique` constraint to whichever column you want unique while creating your database. That should work if i have understood correctly.

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.  Also, `Location:` headers must contain a full URL.  While most browsers will figure out a relative path, to follow the standards, you must use the full URL.

Answer (score 1):

You just should add hidden field containing the id of the post to the comment form.